# Audio being fed back into the circuit, beeping

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, transistors, analog

I am developing an audio amplifier with microphone, I have a problem that I tried in many ways to solve I could not, so I am here to ask you a second opinion.

My problem is that this circuit is generating a lot of feedback is I can not eliminate this whistle, I tried to put the electret microphone in polarization with a resistor, I also tested capacitors of various values ​​in parallel is not resolved (the sound does not come out or distorted ).

I have already tried to lower the value of c17 to decrease the op amp gain from + -702 and the sound comes out noisy.
what do I do.

supply voltage: 12V.

The sound captures the return from afar +- 1 meter

[image]

Comment: Your circuit has no power supply. How is it beeping? OK, it must have a power supply but you haven't shown in and you have no decoupling capacitors. Edit the schematic, add the power supply, show the voltage, take another screengrab (but crop it) and add some decoupling capacitors on the op-amps. Your circuit is missing a volume control so if you have the mic anywhere near the speaker you will get feedback. Try putting the speaker in another room.

Comment: How does reversing speaker polarity affect it?  Why does the noise cancelling fail on mic?  poor front rear balance.  What frequency (s)?

Comment: Disconnect your speaker and use a resistor instead and determine the electrical performance of the circuit with an oscilloscope. I suspect your gain is much too high.

Comment: What power supply are you using?

Comment: And what impedance is the speaker? (if you don't know then measure its resistance with multimeter).

Comment: Why would you *not* expect acoustic feedback? It's a very common problem with acoustic amplifiers.

Answer (score 2):

U8 has a feedback resistor, but no series resistor between the - input and the microphone.

With that setup, U8 just amplifies the microphone signal with everything it's got.

Put a 100k resistor in the place of the connection from C17 to R39.  That will reduce the amplification to about 5.

If that's not enough amplification, use a resistor with a lower value than 100k.

---

This kind of circuit has a natural tendency to develop a feedback squeal.

You amplify the microphone signal, and send it back out through the speaker.

The microphone "hears" what comes out of the speaker, amplifies it again, and again it goes back out of the speaker.  It just keeps getting louder and louder.

You have to turn down the amplification or move the speaker and microphone so that the microphone doesn't "hear" the speaker as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's not the case that your gain is too high and you have acoustic feedback (you can't noise cancel with phase, sound rapidly becomes non coherent)...

You have a number of noise sources:

1. Your amplifier+and- have one terminal driven with a potential divider and one driven with a capacitor. It's therefore liable to oscillate driven by small noise on the psu line.
2. The microphone voltage excitation should be decoupled from the output stage voltage source, otherwise ripple on it will feed back into your transimpedance amplifier. There should be no (DC) current through the microphone so you can use a slow RC network.
3. Your output stage may well not be very nice and linear and therefore producing large (in terms of a high gain trans impedance amplifier) power rail dips and spikes.

Add capacitors to the lower resistors of your voltage dividers and filter the microphone excitation.

Verify first that you're not just getting acoustic feedback... Use a resistor for the speaker as suggested by someone else and an oscilloscope.

Answer (score 0):

You have negative feedback for each amplifier.  If you still have oscillations( sounds like you do), you can add system level negative feedback.  Connect from C9 back to U8 with  a resistor.  That resistor will also set the overall gain of the system.

Answer (score 0):

Your inverting amplifiers have a DC offset of Vcc/2 on their outputs.

The first one has a lot of gain *(A<sub>V1</sub> = -500k / R<sub>out-mic</sub> ... where R<sub>out-mic</sub> is the output [internal] impedance of the microphone. It's probably a few hundreds of Ohms. So Av < -500)*. It can ridiculously amplify any noise on its inv input. And also the output will have an offset of Vcc/2 (6VDC in your case).

The second one has a gain of -3. The inv input has 6VDC offset + amplified signal coming from the previous stage. Since the gain is negative, the DC offset coming from the first stage will not affect the output. But the output will still have a DC offset of Vcc/2 due to the voltage divider consisting of R1 and R2.

This may result in saturating the output of the preamp stage if the input signal coming from the microphone is large enough (e.g. 10mV rms). So you'll get a pure DC output, or a square wave at best.

You may want to build non-inverting amplifiers instead.